# Dynamic input in R apply

Tags: r, input, apply

I was wondering if the apply family could be used in R with a regressive input. 
Say I have:

```
apply(MyMatrix,1,MyFunc,MyMatrix)
```

I know that apply is essentially a loop, so in the above example could it run one iteration of `MyFunc` over the first line of `MyMatrix` modifying `MyMatrix` globally and then select the modified `MyMatrix` for the next iteration ? I realize that normal loops could be used here but I just wanted to know if there is a way to do it like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so.  Even modifying `MyMatrix` globally won't change the `MyMatrix` passed to your function.  R functions don't operate that way.  Your object is actually copied when it's passed into a function and a new instance of it exists then.  It's not done by reference.

Comment: That's what I figured. I was looking to avoid loops altogether but I now figured out that apply is just another loop and I wouldn't really gain any efficiency. Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `*apply` family of functions are able to work in this manner. (This has been a frustration to me at times as well, but I've come to appreciate and work with it.)

There are two impediments to this:

1. The `*apply` family of functions deal with the value of `MyMatrix` when you make the call, iterate over the rows (in this example), and then join the results (based on the dimensions of each output). It is not re-evaluated each time.
2. Even if it did re-evaluate it, `MyFunc` is only given one row (in this example) at a time, not the whole matrix. (Your second reference to `MyMatrix` appears to be working around this.)

To do what I think you're saying, then your `MyFunc` function needs to accept as arguments the entire matrix and the row on which you are operating, and return just the row in question, ala:

```
MyFunc <- function(rownum, mtx) {
    # ...
    mtx[rownum,]
}
```

Using that premise, you could do:

```
for (rr in seq.int(nrow(MyMatrix))) {
    MyMatrix[rr,] <- MyFunc(rr, MyMatrix)
}
```

or, if you must stay with the `*apply` family:

```
MyMatrix.new <- sapply(seq.int(nrow(MyMatrix)), MyFunc, MyMatrix)
```

You might want the transpose (`t()`) of the return from `sapply()` here.

If `MyFunc` returns the whole matrix instead of just one row, this can be done though a little differently.

I know of no way to directly do what you suggest.

Comment: I guess there's no way. I think I got in a bad habit of avoiding loops at all costs even though [I just realized this] apply is basically a loop. Thanks for your time !

Comment: I have avoided loops as well, but recent performance benchmarks show that loops are not necessarily any slower. There are times when the `apply` family provides a truly elegant solution, but I've found myself trying so hard to get that elegance when in fact for loops can be so much more readable. Cheers!